# Google geo chart: tooltip: textStyle not working

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have the following code for a geo chart, where I've tried to specify the colour but the tooltip is showing up in a pale grey on a white background.

Any ideas?

I'm using chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 on a mac.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Working days'],
        ['Greece', 243],
        ['Ireland', 205],
        ['United Kingdom', 162],
        ['Portugal',156],
        ['Belgium',164],
        ['Italy',166],
        ['Luxembourg',153],
        ['Cyprus',150],
        ['Finland',145],
        ['Austria',134],
        ['Norway',126],
        ['France',127],
        ['Netherlands',126],
        ['Denmark',122],
        ['Spain',125],
        ['Sweden',120],
        ['Czech Rep',164],
        ['Germany',119],
        ['Romania',110],
        ['Bulgaria',100],
        ['Lithuania',108],
        ['Slovakia',120],
        ['Slovenia',103],
        ['Estonia',79],
        ['Hungary',104],
        ['Latvia',73],
        ['Poland',70]
        ]);

        var options = {
        backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
        sizeAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 250 },
        region: '150',
        datalessRegionColor: '#AAAAAA',
        tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'hover'},
        colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']},
        legend: 'Days'
    };


        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug.  I filed a report on it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1489); you can "star" the issue to get updates on a fix.

Comment: Thanks asgallant. Whilst I'm heartened that it wasn't me being dumb, it does cause a problem for my project! Interestingly using the same code on the visualisation playground works fine, with black text in the tooltips.

Comment: The normal color for the tooltip is white background and black text.  At a guess, your tooltip color is off because of some CSS on your page.

Comment: Is there a way to call the background colour with an override?

Comment: The short answer is yes, you can override the background color of the tooltips.  You have to dive into the SVG code that generates the chart (VML code for older versions of IE) to figure out how to identify the tooltip, and then write javascript/css that changes the tooltip's background color.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there must be a way of fudging it to force the style to behave itself.

But if reimplementing the whole thing using completely different technology sounds in any way appealing...   you could probably do something similar following this [leaflet choropleth tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)